# Boot menu (setup menu /BIOS) for Lenovo E431 not accessible

Tags: boot, bios, lenovo-laptop

I am struggling to get the boot/BIOS menu for my Lenovo E431 laptop.  I tried Esc, F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F8, F9 F10, F12 and Del, but all failed.
The Lenovo docs: http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/e431_e531_ug_en.pdf  says to use F1, but that doesn't work.

Could anybody help me to get into BIOS or suggest a workaround for enabling VT-x (VERR_VMX_MSR_VMXON_DISABLED error) while trying to setup a virtual box on Oracle VM.

Comment: I think there was some problem with software "dependencypackage", when trying to do the product registeration, this software got reinstalled, then my F1 key function started working and able to enter BIOS.

Thanks for all the help "c0dev".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to press <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. It's possible, that the standard-mode of the keys are set wrong for you.

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes I have tried fn+F1 and F1 both cominations, infact all combinations with and without fn+(F1-to-F12) keys :( No luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Windows8, the operating system now controls access to the [EUFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface), which is a new specification meant to replace the BIOS interface.

In 64-bit Windows 7 (perhaps 32-bit also?), the OS can tell the motherboard to hide the boot/bios menu settings.  One reason it will do so is if you Hibernate your system, instead of shutting it down.

I just had this happen to me; very frustrating!  I let windows recover from Hibernation, then shut it down using "Shutdown", and then my bios/boot options came back.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very hard way:

1.- Remove HDD

2.- Power on and enter to setup

3.- Change Boot Order To 1st USB HDD and save change

4.- Turn off

5.- reinstall HDD

6.- Boot with USB

Works for Me.

After all You need change boot order for security.