# Cannot enter BIOS

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, bios

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my Lenovo E49 for dual boot with my Windows 7. After that I couldn't start Windows and was getting the error that it couldn't startup because of some file being corrupted. So I tried fixing it with Windows 7 installation disk but it failed. Thats when I wiped the whole hard disk (backed-up all the drives) because it had GPT partition and installed Windows 8.1. Now I cannot enter BIOS even after pressing the <kbd>F1</kbd> key as well as <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I even tried removing the CMOS battery to reset the BIOS but no use.

What may be the problem here? Is it because I have completely wiped all partitions? How do I fix it?

Update: I see the "BIOS shadowed" on the splash screen.

Answer (score 4):

By default, a Windows 8/8.1 shutdown is not a real shutdown. Instead, it is hybrid shutdown where contents of memory are saved to disk. This allows for a faster startup. However, turning on the PC after a hybrid shutdown does not allow for pressing F1 or F12 during startup.

---

**Solution**:

There are several ways to enter Setup Utility (F1) or the Boot Menu (F12) on a Microsoft Windows 8/8.1 PC as explained below:

1. Press and hold the Shift key while selecting the Shutdown option in Windows 8. This will make the PC perform a full shutdown instead of a hybrid shutdown. Then F1 or F12 can be pressed successfully during startup.
2. Select Restart instead of Shutdown. Then F1 or F12 can be pressed successfully during startup.
3. Disable the fast startup option in Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Power Options -> Choose what the power buttons do.

It is also possible to access these features from within Windows 8/8.1.

To enter Setup Utility:

1. Open the Charm Bar by pressing Windows Key-C
2. Click on Settings
3. Click on Change PC Settings
4. Click on General
5. Scroll to the bottom and click on Advanced Startup -> Restart Now
6. Click on Troubleshoot
7. Click on Advanced Options
8. Click on UEFI Firmware Settings
9. Click on Restart

To access the Boot Menu:

1. Open the Charm Bar by pressing Windows Key-C
2. Click on Settings
3. Click on Change PC Settings
4. Click on General
5. Scroll to the bottom and click on Advanced Startup -> Restart Now
6. Click on Use A Device
7. Click on Boot Menu

Source: [Lenovo Support](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht076906)

---

I highly expect for above official solution to work, but if it does not work, have a look at the answer for Lenovo E431 on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/737159/bootmenu-setup-menu-bios-for-lenovo-e431-does-not-come)

Answer (score 1):

Bios has nothing to do with the Operating System you have on your HDD so don't worry about it. I think that you just have to be a little faster entering Bios setup

Answer (score 0):

As emirjonb said, the Operating System has nothing to do with the bios, infact the bios is still fully functioning with no HDD's at all.

<kbd>Del</kbd> is sometimes the key to enter the BIOS, most likely your just need to be faster, keep pressing the key from bootup until you are in the bios.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get Win8/8.1 to do a full shutdown by typing it into a command prompt:

"shutdown /s /f /t 0"
(from   http://www.thewindowsclub.com/force-full-shutdown-fully-reinitialize-windows-8)

Given that you're dual-booting though, you probably want to disable the hybrid shutdown anyway.  I've had to do the same on the Win10 test laptop I dual-boot with.  As a bonus, I can now see the contents of Win10's OS partition from Linux too.

EDIT: Playing with any other setting in BIOS should be much easier after Win isn't doing the hybrid thing.

Comment: i have tried doing the complete shutdown but the problem persists. also i have noticed "BIOS shadowed" coming up on the splash screen.

Comment: 'bios shadowed/'video shadowed'  seem to be normal for some motherboards (seems its loading the bios into ram and running from there.

Comment: [apparently Enter when typing a comment is not a new line...]

Thanks to Lenovo's asinine naming conventions, I'm not sure which of these categories you fall under as far as buttons to use to get into bios, but might be worth it to try some of the combinations here:
http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht036045

Only other thing I can think of to try is to "update" the bios (with the same version or later) from Win, if you can still get there, idea being to reset it to defaults.